# Best way to create/edit a template programatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I could use FrameworkElementFactory to create a template, but this class is deprecated. The recommended way, according to MSDN is to use XamlReader.Load to load XAML from a string or a memory stream. I get this to work, but think this is kind of sad:

```
string xaml = "a lot of XAML";
```

Any suggestions to be able to do this in a better way?

What I really want to do is be able to dynamically change a Binding path in a DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Some text</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThePathIWantToChange}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Could you explain little more? What path are you trying to change?

Comment: I added some XAML to better show what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Jostein,

Wouldn't it be easier to change the property value and rise PropertyChanged event? Approach with updating whole data template looks like overkill for me.

Comment: I'm using the DataGrid from the WPFToolkit, but don't know what or how many columns I have at compile time. I use the AutoGeneratingColumn event of the DataGrid to set different column types based on some info in a business object. In some cases I need to use the DataGridTemplateColumn, and thus set the CellEditingTemplate and CellTemplate. When I set theese templates I would like the binding to be set to the current PropertyName given by the DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs object. I'm not sure how I could apply your approach in this case?